# ipsec auto --status fails in cronjob

Tags: centos, cron, ipsec

I have a server monitoring script which, among other things, checks the state of an IPSec tunnel using

```
ipsec auto --status
```

It works like a charm when run from the console (as root) but as soon as I run it from a (root) cronjob, the command fails: no output at all.

I even tried to create this simple root cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * ipsec auto --status > /tmp/ipsec.txt
```

All it does is create an empty /tmp/ipsec.txt file!

Note: All other tasks in the script including networking and DB access work fine.

Any lights welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like `cron` is not seeing `ipsec` in the path. It's a pretty good habit to include absolute paths to binaries in crontab. There is probably some complaining in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/cron`.

`*/1 * * * * /usr/sbin/ipsec auto --status`

You could also add the `PATH` environment variable to the top of the crontab. The `PATH` will apply to all the jobs in the crontab.

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
*/1 * * * * /usr/sbin/ipsec auto --status
```

Comment: ha! What a dork! errr... me. not you :-)